# Configure Prestashop Webservice using docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, prestashop

I am trying to simplify the installation of Prestashop by using docker containers.  My issue is that the container must be API ready once loaded but I can’t find a way to enable this feature from docker-compose.

**What I’m trying to accomplish:**

1. Enable Prestashop's Webservice
2. Create a webservice key
3. Create permissions for the webservice
4. Be able to modify products, customers, addresses etc. from Postman

**Things I have done so far:**

```
services:
    prestashopper:
        image: prestashop/prestashop
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            - PS_LANGUAGE=en
            - PS_COUNTRY=CO
            - PS_FOLDER_ADMIN=admin_folder_name
            - PS_FOLDER_INSTALL=install_folder_name
            - PS_INSTALL_AUTO=1
            - PS_DOMAIN=localhost:8080
            - PS_WEBSERVICE=1
        command:
            [
            #     php -r 'Configuration::updateValue('PS_WEBSERVICE', 1);'
            #     php -r '$$apiAccess = new WebserviceKey();',
            #     php -r '$$apiAccess->key = GENERATED_KEY;',
            #     php -r '$$apiAccess->save();',
            ]
```

**What my research has told me:**

Based on the [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/creating-access/) on the PrestaShop website, these commands can be done using PHP, however, I was unable to determine how to correctly run these PHP commands from a docker-compose setup

Also is it possible to modify the following from docker-compose

- Modify currency options
- Change shop's main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a dedicated PHP script in your container or mounted volume
where you need to bootstrap Prestashop framework
(include **/init.php** and **/config/config.inc.php**) so you can launch those
Prestashop core commands afterwards.

You can use docker exec to execute it after cointaner had started:

```
docker exec -it -w $PWD php_worker php /home/my_post_install_script.php
```

Regarding modify currency options, have a look at **classes/Currency.php** , there all all the methods to interact with Currency object.

Regarding updating shop main activity, this is the **PS_SHOP_ACTIVITY** key in Configuration table , so a

```
Configuration::updateValue(PS_SHOP_ACTIVITY, your_id)
```

will do the trick. You can find various option values in backoffice dropdown list.